# ¿Cómo puedo borrar todos los datos de una tabla en ASP MVC entity framework?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación web con asp MVC y tengo el formulario por defecto del Entity Framework, me gustaría saber si hay una forma de que en un botón pueda limpiar o borrar todos los datos registrado de la tabla al que pertenece ese formulario.

Código:

```
// GET: Clientes/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Clientes clientes = db.Clientes.Find(id);
        if (clientes == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(clientes);
    }

    // POST: Clientes/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Clientes clientes = db.Clientes.Find(id);
        db.Clientes.Remove(clientes);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si los registros no tienen relación con otras tablas puedes usar esta instrucción:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [TableName]");
```

Comment: Perfecto me sirvio de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Otra metodo seria :

```
            db.Tabla.RemoveRange(db.Tabla.ToList());
```